# HTML UTF-8 different 'de facto'-font-sizes

Tags: html, css, select, utf-8, font-size

I want to make a Country-Picker with a select (in the original, foreign language). The characters in some languages are greater than others (with same font size).

```
<select>
    <option>Cambodia (កម្ពុជា)</option>
    <option>Deutschland (Germany)</option>
</select>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/93Xnc/

How can I fix this? I cannot change the font-size within an `<option>`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you want to happen?

Comment: That the height of the foreign characters is as big as the height of normal characters

Comment: It could depends on the fonts you have installed on your system. What OS, what language and what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by using multiple typefaces and various font sizes for your options.

Example:

```
<option style="font-family:Comic Sans MS,arial,serif;font-size:13px">Cambodia (កម្ពុជា)</option>
<option style="font-family:Arial,serif,sans-serif;font-size:11px">Deutschland (Germany)</option>
```

You can find plenty of typefaces in [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts). Just find those that best fit to your options and adjust the font-sizes accordingly.